# how to print forward slash using Zebra Programming Language

Tags: zpl, zpl-ii

I am trying to print static text "Contact/Ven" in zebra sticker using a ZPL but instead of printing "Contact/Ven", it is printing as per the below image.

[image]

Can anyone suggest how to print correct text "Contact/Ven" ?

My code looks like below

```
^XA ^CF0,32 ^FO30,70^FDTest^FS

^CF0,22 ^FO400,65^FDMfg. by Test^FS

^CF0,18 ^FO400,95^FD12742 E Caley Ave Suite E^FS

^FX Third section with QR code and table in a single row. ^CI28 ^FO30,110^BQ,2,3^FDQA,PKG: {{PACKAGE_NAME}}, Weight: {{PACKAGE_WEIGHT}}, LOT#: {{LOT_NUMBER}}, BT#: {{BATCH_TYPE}}, Receive Date: {{RECEIVE_DATE}}, Contact/Ven: {{CONTACT_NAME}}, DES: {{DEPARTMENT}}, Use by Date: {{USE_BY_DATE}}, Manufactured Date: {{MANUFACTURED_DATE}}^FS ^FO10,50^GB770,335,4^FS

^CF0,20 ^FO280,140^FDPKG^FS ^FO440,140^FDTets^FS

^FO280,175^FDWeight^FS ^FO440,175^FDTets^FS

^FO280,210^FDLOT#^FS ^FO440,210^FDTets^FS

^FO280,245^FDBT#^FS ^FO440,245^FDTets^FS

^CI28 ^FO280,280^FDContact/Ven^FS ^FO440,280^FDTets^FS

^FO280,315^FDDES^FS ^FO440,315^FDTets^FS

CI28 ^FO30,350^FH^FDRcvd. Date: 07\2F12\2F2023 Manufactured Date: 07\2F12\2F2023
Use by Date: 07\2F12\2F2023 ^FS ^XZ
```

Comment: Can you show your actual code?

Comment: What printer model are you using? Are you printing anything else to this printer from another program?

Answer (score 0):

[Educated guess]

Change

```
^FDContact/Ven
```

to

```
^FH^FDContact\2FVen
```

Given that the date string provided by the last code line is being produced correctly. `\2F` being hex-code `2F`=`/`

Answer (score 0):

The output of your label with Labelary is:
[image]

For the last line on your label, the ZPL is:

```
^FO30,350^FH^FDRcvd. Date: 07\2F12\2F2023 Manufactured Date: 07\2F12\2F2023
Use by Date: 07\2F12\2F2023 ^FS
```

The command `^FH` needs a parameter character, Like this `^FH\`

If you are having problems with other parts of your label, look into using that command properly to fix it.

**Additional documentation**

`^FH` hexIndicator
Configures the hexadecimal escape character, allowing the current field to embed character codes in the field data. This can be particularly useful when field data values may contain characters which would otherwise be interpreted as ZPL command or parameter delimiters.

Parameters:

> hexIndicator: The hexadecimal escape character. Any ASCII character
> may be used, except the lowercase letters a-z and the ZPL command and
> parameter delimiters.

Example (common usage): `^FH_`